# Keras Tensorflow, only Adam optomizer works. All other optimizers produce none value error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using keras optimizers other than adam and adamax create a value error. Full stack of the error is included in the bottom of the post.

```
None values not supported.  
Python 2.7.13
tensorflow-gpu (1.4.1)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.4.0rc3)
```

Below is the code for defining the network.
    shp = X_train.shape[1:]
    print shp

```
dropout_rate = 0.25
# Optim

#opt = Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.0,clipvalue=0.5)  breaks the code
#dopt = Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.0,clipvalue=0.5) breaks the code
#dopt = Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0) breaks the code
#opt =  Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0) breaks the code
#opt = Nadam(lr=0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, schedule_decay=0.004) breaks the code
#dopt = Nadam(lr=0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, schedule_decay=0.004) breaks the code

opt = Adam(lr=1e-3)
dopt = Adamax(lr=1e-4)
# Build Generative model ...
nch = 200
g_input = Input(shape=[100])
H = Dense(nch*14*14, init='glorot_normal')(g_input)
H = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Reshape( [nch, 14, 14] )(H)
H = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(H)
H = Convolution2D(nch/2, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='glorot_uniform')(H)
H = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Convolution2D(nch/4, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='glorot_uniform')(H)
H = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Convolution2D(1, 1, 1, border_mode='same', init='glorot_uniform')(H)
g_V = Activation('sigmoid')(H)
generator = Model(g_input,g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
generator.summary()
# Build Discriminative model ...
d_input = Input(shape=shp)
H = Convolution2D(256, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode = 'same', activation='relu')(d_input)
H = LeakyReLU(0.2)(H)
H = Dropout(dropout_rate)(H)
H = Convolution2D(512, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode = 'same', activation='relu')(H)
H = LeakyReLU(0.2)(H)
H = Dropout(dropout_rate)(H)
H = Flatten()(H)
H = Dense(256)(H)
H = LeakyReLU(0.2)(H)
H = Dropout(dropout_rate)(H)
d_V = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(H)
discriminator = Model(d_input,d_V)
discriminator.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=dopt)
discriminator.summary()
gan_input = Input(shape=[100])
H = generator(gan_input)
gan_V = discriminator(H)
GAN = Model(gan_input, gan_V)
GAN.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
GAN.summary()
```

[Keras Gan example](https://github.com/osh/KerasGAN) 
The code is based of of the following example, MNIST_CNN_GAN_v2. 
Is their a simple fix to fix the NONE value error.

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-15c932193e1f> in <module>()
 16 
 17 make_trainable(discriminator,True)
 ---> 18 discriminator.fit(X,y, epochs =1, batch_size=128)
 19 y_hat = discriminator.predict(X)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in     fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
1632         else:

1633             ins = x + y + sample_weights

->1634         self._make_train_function()
1635         f = self.train_function
1636 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _make_train_function(self)
988                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
989                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 990                         loss=self.total_loss)
991                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
992                 # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.pyc in   wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
 85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
 86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
 ---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
 88         wrapper._original_function = func
 89         return wrapper

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.pyc in get_updates(self, loss, params)
295             new_a = a + K.square(g)  # update accumulator
296             self.updates.append(K.update(a, new_a))
--> 297             new_p = p - lr * g / (K.sqrt(new_a) + self.epsilon)
298 
299             # Apply constraints.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.pyc in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
883       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
884         try:
--> 885           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
886         except TypeError:
887           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
834       name=name,
835       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 836       as_ref=False)
837 
838 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
924 
925     if ret is None:
--> 926       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
927 
928     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.pyc in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
227                                          as_ref=False):
228   _ = as_ref
--> 229   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
230 
231 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.pyc in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
206   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
207       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 208           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
209   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
210   const_tensor = g.create_op(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.pyc in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
369   else:
370     if values is None:
--> 371       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
372     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
373     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please post your expected behavior and format the error in a way that is easier for users to spot.

Comment: Error message formatted

Comment: @Daniel, I included the stack trace of the error. There is to much code for the entire network for training and evaluation, to post in stack overflow. Let me know if there is specifically anything else you would like to see. The training and evaluation code can be found with the given link.

Answer (score 0):

For me, having 
epsilon = None is optimizer definition in below declaration was causing this issue.
Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None)